# KeyError: 'request' with django-notifications-hq and Django 3.2

Tags: python, django

I use [django-notifications-hq](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) and recently updated my project from Django version 2.2 to 3.2. Ever since, I get KeyError: 'response' whenever  I try to access a template that uses the `notifications_unread` templatetag. Using [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I was able to notice that the template context no longer has the `request` key, that was present before the update. What am I missing here?

The traceback:

```
Template error:
In template /var/www/my_project/src/my_project/mp_frontend/templates/front/notifications.html, error at line 10
   request
   1 : {% load user_profile_tags %}
   2 : {% load notifications_tags %}
   3 : {% load i18n %}
   4 : {% load custom_notification_tags %}
   5 : 
   6 : <li class="dropdown notification-list">
   7 :     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle  waves-effect" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
   8 :        aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">
   9 :         <i class="far fa-bell">
   10 :              {% notifications_unread as unread_count %} 
   11 :             {% if unread_count %}
   12 :                 <span class="badge badge-danger rounded-circle noti-icon-badge">{{ unread_count }}</span>
   13 :             {% endif %}
   14 :         </i>
   15 :     </a>
```

My code:

```py
def list_products(request):
    profile = get_user_profile_from_request(request)
    context = {'user_tkn': profile.generate_new_token()}
    return render(request, 'label_catalog/products/index.html', context=context)
```

And if I change it to:

```py
def list_products(request):
    profile = get_user_profile_from_request(request)
    context = {'request':request, 'user_tkn': profile.generate_new_token()}
    return render(request, 'label_catalog/products/index.html', context=context)
```

everything works fine. I've searched through django-notifications-hq's issues and Django's release notes but haven't found anything helpful.

Note: the template `products/index.html` includes `front/notifications.html` as so: `{% include 'front/notifications.html' %}`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding that the problem was between the keyboard and the seat.
On the process of upgrading the Django version, for some reason I commented out the request context processor on settings.py. Here's my templates settings for anyone out there who may encounter this issue:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['my_project/mp_frontend/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',  # this line waas the key
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```